# Slim v2 to Slim v3 Upgrade

Tags: php, instance, upgrade, slim

I have been using Slim v2 for my APIs and am thinking about upgrading to v3.
Unfortunately I have limited experience and could use your help on a code example below.

This is the login code:

```
$app->post('/register', function() use ($app) {
        // check for required params
        verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'email', 'password'));

        $response = array();

        // reading post params
        $name = $app->request->post('name');
        $email = $app->request->post('email');
        $password = $app->request->post('password');

        // validating email address
        validateEmail($email);

        $db = new DbHandler();
        $res = $db->createUser($name, $email, $password);

        if ($res == USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY) {
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
        } else if ($res == USER_CREATE_FAILED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred while registereing";
        } else if ($res == USER_ALREADY_EXISTED) {
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Sorry, this email already existed";
        }
        // echo json response
        echoRespnse(201, $response);
    });
```

Here is the validateEmail function:

```
function validateEmail($email) {
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = 'Email address is not valid';
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
```

}

How do I get an Instance of app in Slim v3 to actually stop the app when input criteria are not met?
I would appreciate it if you could give me an example with the help of my code.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

The above issue was solved. Unfortunately, a new issue arose after checking my code.

I have a middle layer to authenticate the user:

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
// Getting request headers
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$response = array();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

// Verifying Authorization Header
if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    //omitted code
} else {
    // api key is missing in header
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
```

In my main code i implement function authenticate as follows:

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

       //ommit some code

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });
```

Would you know how to do this in Slim v3?
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Slim3, `return $response` (return Response object) is a better way to stop app.
So how is the below?

```
$app->post('/register', function($request, $response, $args) {
    // omit some codes
    if(!validateEmail($request->getParsedBodyParam('email'))){
        return $response->withJson(['message' => 'Email address is not valid', 'error' => true], 400);   
    }
    // omit some codes
}
```

validateEmail function is changed to like below.

```
function validateEmail($email) {

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a good workaround for the problem I was facing.
Much appreciated.
Unfortunately, a new issue arose.
I edited the above question, because that issue was solved.

Comment: In slim3 you can use middleware. Pls take a look at the following link.  http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html

Comment: And you can get header from $request object.  `$request->getHeaders();`